# Drop down list of month and year for parameter in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I would like to display month and year for my parameter for the end users to select from the drop down list.

For example the startdate has to be June 2017 and enddate is only month and year from `getdate()`

This is the query that I wrote but it's not working for me

```
declare @start datetime = '6/1/2017'
declare @end datetime = getdate()

select 
    @start = dateadd(M, @start), 
    datename(M, @start) + ' ' + datename(Y, @start)
where 
    @start < @end
```

Comment: where is this code? in SSRS somewhere?

Comment: What output do you expect to see from this query?

Comment: the code is in sql server. the output I was to see is drop down list of  month and year. For example june 2017,july 2017,August 2017.... up to month and year from getdate()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors in your code:

1. Syntax of dateadd, correct `dateadd(MONTH,1, @start)`
2. You are returning the error `A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.`

Try these code

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME = '2017-01-01' 
DECLARE @end DATETIME = Getdate(); 

WITH ctealldates 
     AS (SELECT @start startdate 
                ,@end  enddate 
         FROM   (VALUES (1))G(n) 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT Dateadd(month, 1, startdate) startdate 
                ,enddate 
         FROM   ctealldates 
         WHERE  startdate < enddate) 
SELECT Datename(month, startdate) + ' ' 
                + Datename(year, startdate) MonthName, year(startdate) * 100 + month(startdate) OrderBy
FROM   ctealldates 
ORDER BY
    year(startdate) * 100 + month(startdate)
OPTION (maxrecursion 0); 



MonthName                                                     OrderBy
------------------------------------------------------------- -----------
January 2017                                                  201701
February 2017                                                 201702
March 2017                                                    201703
April 2017                                                    201704
May 2017                                                      201705
June 2017                                                     201706
July 2017                                                     201707
August 2017                                                   201708
September 2017                                                201709
```

Comment: No Problem. Please change the 
Dateadd(day, 1, startdate) startdate  to Dateadd(month, 1, startdate) startdate, it will improve the performance and remove the disitinct.

Answer (score 0):

one Solution that i think will be as below.

1. Create a stored procedure as below

   ```
   declare @start DATE = '2011-05-01'
   declare @end DATE = getdate()
   ;with months (date)
   AS
   (
      SELECT @start
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(month,1,date)
      from months
      where DATEADD(month,1,date)<=@end
   )
   select Datename(month,date) As Months, Datename(year, date) As Years, CONCAT(Datename(month,date), ' ', Datename(year, date)) As MonthandYear from months
   ```
2. create a parameter for your report RDL, and for available values option select get values from Query.

[image]
Select created dataset from above query, in value field select MonthandYear field and label as 'Start Date'.

When you run the report you should receive input parameter as Start Date with drop down values for date difference with start date and end date.

hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. Your query was right too.